# Document Properties Under Quick Parts Don't Update When A New Column Is Created

Tags: content-type, document-set, quick-parts

I have a SharePoint 2013 site that contains a document set with multiple content types.  Each content type has its own document template.  When I open a document template in Word, and then select Quick Parts -> Document Property, I can see all the properties related to the content type.  However, if I add a new column to the content type and then open the template again in Word, I don't see the new column in the list of properties when I select Quick Parts -> Document Property.  Is there an additional step that needs to be taken after a new column is added, in order for it to show up under Quick Parts?

Comment: Did you check if the column is present in the default content type?

Comment: OK, I must've done somehing wrong, because I just added a new site column and added it to the content type.  After doing so, I opened the template in Word and verified that the column is showing up under Document Properties.  I had copied the content types and site columns from a SharePoint 2010 site, so maybe something in the export process had something to do with the issue I was experiencing, I don't know.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you originally create your new site column in SharePoint Designer, which wouldn't show in the Quick Parts. And then you tried creating one through the GUI, and it showed?

Answer (score 0):

Just wait 10 minutes. Some timer jobs must be completed.